# Blender Randomly Reboots My Computer When Processing or Rendering

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, eevee-render-engine, error

So I've recently started picking up blender as a new skill, but early in the gate I've run into a pretty major issue. Despite having a pretty beefy computer (will post specs below), Blender will restart my computer when doing nearly any realtime rendering or still/animation rendering. I work in the adobe suite every day and have never had this problem even while pushing out beefy comps or psds. I can pretty much run the entire suite at once with no problem but Blender for some reason just shuts off the machine.

**What I've Tried**

- **Updating the GPU driver**
- **Using Previous Versions of Blender**
- **Command Line Rendering** (this works, but isn't a great solution given it still reboots the computer if its looking at nearly anything in the viewport)
- **Exporting on Another Machine** (the file works fine, it rendered out without issue on my partner's laptop)
- **Checking Task Manager while rendering** (nothing is shooting up to intense, no columns go past the 35%ish range)
- **Checking Event Viewer** (I can trace back to a Critical Error, **Kernel Power, Event ID 41**)
- **Benchmarking the System** (everything is in the good category, explains why my other software works fine)
- **"Checking" Crash Logs** (There aren't any. I can't find any in the temp folder, I read somewhere that blender wipes them after a reboot?)

I wanna guess this is a GUI issue? I don't know why it'd be doing this with a computer I got like 4 months ago. I **really** wanna pick up this software but it becomes a non starter if I cant even model a rock in Eevee without it randomly rebooting my system. Can anyone offer any insight as to how to fix this?

**Computer Specs:**

```
AMD Ryzen 5 3600 3.6 GHz 6-Core Processor

Gigabyte B550M AORUS PRO-P Micro ATX AM4 Motherboard

Corsair Vengeance RGB Pro 32 GB (2 x 16 GB) DDR4-3200 CL16 Memory

Samsung 980 Pro 250 GB M.2-2280 NVME Solid State Drive

MSI GeForce RTX 3060 Ti 8 GB VENTUS 2X OC Video Card

Corsair RM (2019) 650 W 80+ Gold Certified Fully Modular ATX Power Supply
```

[image: Here is the Error Description]

Comment: What are you used for rendering?  GPU or CPU or both

Comment: When you say you card is OC x 2, is it sold as an OC model, or did you overclock manually? Blender doesn't like manual overclocks, unfortunately (especially memory overclocking), so make sure you're running base speeds. Another (albeit less likely) cause may have to do with your Timeout Detection and Recovery (TDR) settings. Info about it here - https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/display/timeout-detection-and-recovery

Comment: One thing to look into is this new issue of 'transient power spikes' in the 3000 series GPUs.  A 650w power supply may be vulnerable.

Comment: Maybe there is an error in the hard disk, that happened to me last year too, I used the [CrystalDiskInfo](https://crystalmark.info/en/software/crystaldiskinfo/) program to see the status of my disks and indeed the disk where I was rendering was failing.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue! And it blew my mind for several months! I found the solution.

The problem is CPU power settings in BIOS.
There is voltage protection that turnoff PC after some voltage threshold. You need to set it to some higher value.

Different vendors call this option in a different ways, but with similar words.

In my case:

**BIOS -> Advanced -> VRM settings -> CPU Current Capability**

I chose the "extreme" profile option, a max range for voltage, and I have good cooling for the CPU.

Comment: Wow. An answer that can lead to processor damage... That certainly deserves a downvote. Terrible advice.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Cycles rendering engine, try turning off *Denoise* and increasing the number of samples.
Hope this will help, I had the similar problem back 2 months ago.